# Write a small program, sleepy, that gets a loop count from the command line

Tags: c, ubuntu, process, operating-system

I need some help in my task. The question is " Write a small program, sleepy, that gets a loop count from the command line:
sleepy n
where n is the number of seconds for which the program should run. Implement this timing by putting a loop n times of sleep(1) - this will put the program to sleep for one second n times before exiting. In each loop print out the process ID and the loop count so that that particular process can be identified.

Comment: `argc` is the number of command line arguments, not the numeric value of one of the arguments. Do you expect to run your program like `sleepy 5` to let it sleep for 5 seconds? Then I suggest to convert `argv[1] to a number using `strtol`.

Comment: @Bodo Noted your point. Can you please take a look at the code once more bcz i have added the second part of the question and provided the code i have done. Also there is only one process running now. what if we want multiple!

Comment: Please state in your question what you have changed (that you added the suggested code from nivpeled's answer) and what other question you have or what is not working as expected. (What input do you use, what output/result do you expect and what do you actually get or what actually happens?)

Comment: @Bodo I have mentioned

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me. I don't know what problem or question you have now. If the question is now related to your own implementation of a function `sleep`, which was not present in the original question, then this belongs to a separate question. In this case revert your changes here, because the existing answers no longer match the question, and ask a new question. You can add a link to this question for reference. Make sure to clearly explain your problem or question in the new question.

Comment: @Bodo Okay I will ask a new question.

Comment: I reverted the question to the first version to make it match the existing answers. The previous edit of the OP removed the whole code instead of showing the original problem.

Comment: Please don't remove the original code. The question and answer are not only for you, they will be archived here for later reference or for other users searching for similar questions. Removing the code will render the existing answers nearly useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

1. check that `argc` is 2 exactly (sleepy and n).
2. counter needs to loop till `argv[1]`
3. sleep for 1 sec in each loop iteration.

```
    if (argc == 2) {
    for (counter = 0; counter<atoi(argv[1]); counter++) {

        sleep(1); // sleep function which is taking the number from cmd and performing afterwards.
        printf("Awake!\n");

        printf("\n count[%d]",counter); // printing loop counting, and argument passed in cmd

        printf("Process ID: %d\n",p_id); //printing the process ids
    }
```

Comment: can you please read the question and let me know if there is anything missing.

Comment: @Developer'sMind all 3 changes I have mentioned in my answer are missing and required in your code.

Comment: @Developer'sMind only if your have a doubt/question regarding your solution to the second part.

Comment: @Developer'sMind I do not see any requirement to have more than 1 process.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is executed once per each arguments from the command line (argc), whereas the requirement is to parse the the number of iterations from the (first) command line arguments (argv[1])

You also want to change the sleep to 1 seconds, as per requirement.

```
int count = atoi(argv[1]) ;
for (counter = 0; counter<count ; counter++) {
   sleep (1) ;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please recheck, there is only one process running now. what if we want multiple!

Comment: I'm not sure which process you refer to.